# How to use "regions" as Firebase Remote Config condition?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-remote-config

When defining a new condition for Firebase Remote Config, I can see that there's the condition of "Country/Region". However, after tapping on the "Select countries/regions" only countries are available in the list - unlike in Audiences where regions like "Texas" are selectable. Does anyone know how to use the region as an RC condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation regarding [condition rule types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#condition_rule_types), at "Country/Region" it is said:

> Select one or more regions **or** countries.

> This rule evaluates to true for a given app instance if the instance is in any of the regions or countries listed.

So it's a country **or** a region and not a country **and** a region. So you cannot select a region within a particular country. And it makes sense since when you create a rule, the device country code is determined using the device's IP address in the request or the country code determined by Firebase Analytics (if Analytics data is shared with Firebase).

Comment: Thanks. I was not trying to select both country AND region, instead I was looking for regions only. However in the list there are only countries.

Comment: Yes, only countries are displayed in that section.

Comment: It seems the only way to achieve it is to use Audiences as a condition. But I've found that I need to put a delay up to 10 seconds to fetch Remote Config again after the first fetch, so as to be in that audience and trigger the condition. Is that the way to do it?

Comment: If it solves the problem, why not?

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Thank you that's all I need to know. Should we accept the comment as the right answer?